# Android Studio Java Google Maps: draw multiple markers - For loop breaks app

Tags: java, google-maps, android-studio, for-loop, google-maps-api-3

I am a novice to programming and I am truly stuck with this problem, which is certainly trivial but nevertheless, I have been unsuccessfully trying to solve it for several days now.
I read from a txt file the location for markers, add them to an ArrayList and then parse the String to get the data to add a new marker.
This works without problems when I do it one for one, but as soon as I want to use a for loop, the app crashes and won't draw the markers.
Could you pls help me out here? Thanks a lot in advance!

```
ArrayList<String> contents = new ArrayList<String>();

public void LoadLocations() throws IOException {
    String str="";
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.where_water1);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    if (is!=null) {

        while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            contents.add(str);
                    }
    }
    is.close();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //shows the map
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    configureLocationUpdates();

    try {
        LoadLocations();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Problems: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

This is how I do it "manually" which does put a marker on the map (in this case line 11 of the text file)

```
String[] splitted = contents.get(10).split(",");
LatLng fountainLoc = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(splitted[0]), Double.parseDouble(splitted[1]));
String address = splitted[2] + ", " + splitted[3];
m_map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(fountainLoc)
            .title(address)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
```

However, if I put this code into a for loop, the app crashes:

```
        for (int i = 0; i<contents.size(); i++){
        String[] splittedI = contents.get(i).split(",");
        double latI = Double.parseDouble(splittedI[0]);
        double lngI = Double.parseDouble(splittedI[1]);
        LatLng fountainLocI = new LatLng(latI, lngI);
        String addressI = splittedI[2] + ", " + splittedI[3];

        m_map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(fountainLocI)
                .title(addressI)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN)));}
```

Really appreciate your feedback and help!

Comment: Better use `for (String line : contents) {` instead of `for (int i = 0; i<contents.size(); i++){` - it is safer. Then you can refer it like `String[] splittedI = line.split(",");`. Is it throwing some exception?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your reply. I found my error, there were some whitespaces around the strings I want to parse to doubles. Duh... Thanks a lot for your effort and your tip!